# How to properly Setup Spring lemon in my project?

Tags: spring-lemon

i am beginner spring boot developer
I have developed a simple REST CRUD IN my spring boot project, now  i want to setup  lemon in project, but i can not understand it from lemon's github
can any one help me setup in my project .

Lemon in my spring boot,